# Dual Boot - Ubuntu 9.10, 10.04 - /home Cannot Be Initialized Upon Startup

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, ubuntu-10.04

This post have been moved to the Ubuntu site:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/2997/dual-boot-ubuntu-9-10-10-04-home-cannot-be-initialized-upon-startup

Comment: Some additional information may help: the output of `fdisk -l`, and the contents on `/etc/fstab` on both installations. Also, if relevant, information on any encryption, RAID, lvm or other “advanced” setup.

Comment: I ran `fdsik -l` and got no output.  See edit above for `/etc/fstab` contents...

Comment: I forgot to mention that you must run `fdsik -l` as root. In fact, given your `fstab`, please run `fdisk -l /dev/sda` as root.

Comment: Also, please report the output of `blkid /dev/sda*` (also as root).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `UUID=fc128610-a6d5-4d23-9898-064580419da0` partition (so `/home` for 9.10) is missing?  Or is that on another disk than `sda`?

Comment: Yes, this UUID seems to be missing.  I have been looking through the output of the commands in the original post.  What exactly needs to be done to get back on track?  If the UUID ending in 19da0 is missing, can I add the UUID I want to be at `/home` to the appropriate `fstab` and get it to work?  This aspect of Linux is still new to me and that is probably why I screed it up in the first place.  Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the question you ask:  "...is that on another disk than `sda`?"  There is only one disk on the machine and it has several partitions.  My intention was to a two Ubuntu installations, 9.10 as 64-bit and 10.04 as 32-bit.